# How to add attributes with namespace with XSLT when there is a default namespace on the XML

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is the root of my XML (There is more to it but here is the basis):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><section xmlns="http://quark.com/smartcontent/2.0" id="_63f6a0c9-bac8-4a15-854c-03d80bd46b64" type="clientFactsheet">
```

Here is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:deltaxml="http://www.deltaxml.com/ns/well-formed-delta-v1" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="*|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="section[@id]">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:attribute name="deltaxml:key" select="@id"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Here is the output XML root:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><section xmlns="http://quark.com/smartcontent/2.0" id="_63f6a0c9-bac8-4a15-854c-03d80bd46b64" type="clientFactsheet">
```

Here is what I get if I take off the default namespace from the input XML (which is desired result, except that I need to keep the default namespace):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><section xmlns:deltaxml="http://www.deltaxml.com/ns/well-formed-delta-v1" deltaxml:key="_63f6a0c9-bac8-4a15-854c-03d80bd46b64" id="_63f6a0c9-bac8-4a15-854c-03d80bd46b64" type="clientFactsheet">
```

Basically, I need to be able to add the "deltaxml:key" attributes with the "id" value of the section so for this I need to add the namespace "deltaxml" but I also need to keep the default namespace (which can change from document to document which I won't have control over... so I can't just copy it over). How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also need to keep the default namespace (which can change from
>   document to document

It is a rare situation where the namespace of the incoming XML is unknown in advance. This puts you at a disadvantage, since trying to match/select a node by its local name only may easily result in matching/selecting other nodes with the same local name, but in different namespaces/s.

If you cannot avoid it, try something along these lines:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:deltaxml="http://www.deltaxml.com/ns/well-formed-delta-v1">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*:section[@id]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="deltaxml:key" select="@id"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following input example:

**XML**

```
<section xmlns="http://quark.com/smartcontent/2.0" 
         id="_63f6a0c9-bac8-4a15-854c-03d80bd46b64" 
         type="clientFactsheet">
<!-- content -->
</section>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<section xmlns="http://quark.com/smartcontent/2.0"
         xmlns:deltaxml="http://www.deltaxml.com/ns/well-formed-delta-v1"
         deltaxml:key="_63f6a0c9-bac8-4a15-854c-03d80bd46b64"
         id="_63f6a0c9-bac8-4a15-854c-03d80bd46b64"
         type="clientFactsheet"><!-- content --></section>
```